# Put a task to the background with bash

Tags: bash

I know that you can start a background job with Bash doing `foo &`. However, the best way I know to put a foreground job to the background is to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to pause it then `bg 1` to resume it in the background.

Is there a faster way? Some <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Something</kbd> key combination I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't. The terminal reinterprets <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> as `SIGTSTP` independently of bash putting the process into the background. See the `susp` option of `stty` as well as the `signal(7)` man page.

Answer (score 5):

You could bind a keystroke to `bg` (no argument means the current job) then you could do

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Something</kbd>

So it would be just two keystrokes. You wouldn't want to use `bg 1` in case there are more than one job present.